# Copying files to multiple directories at a time using bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to copy a file to multiple directories at a time and change in one place of that file according to directory,. I have write a bash script like this-

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                      
for i in {48..0..2}
do
cp extract-z.tcl $i\A/
cp extract-z.tcl $i\A-r/
sed -i "s/-24/-$i/g" $i\A/extract-z.tcl
sed -i "s/-24/--$i/g" $i\A-r/extract-z.tcl
done
```

And I execute it by-

```
chmod +x filename.sh

./filename.sh
```

But it is showing-

```
bash: ./copy.sh: Permission denied
```

I can  not understand what is wrong with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can understand from the error it relates to permissions. Is your script named copy.sh by chance?

If so, make sure you run the script with user who has permission to run it, and this user has permissions to all involved directories (on which folder are you running this script?)

Can you share your `ls -l` on the directory you execute it?
Once you fix the permissions, it would work.

Comment: Yes, I named the script as copy.sh. ls -l of that directory is-drwxr-xr-x 3 ryeasmin42 domain^users    4096 Jul 31 11:44 0A
-rw------- 1 ryeasmin42 domain^users 2401708 Jul 27 11:54 0A-r
drwxr-xr-x 3 ryeasmin42 domain^users    4096 Jul 31 13:35 10A
drwxr-xr-x 3 ryeasmin42 domain^users    4096 Jul 31 13:33 10A-

Comment: Sorry, the ls-l is too long to post here. I have just posted some of its portion. I am wondering if it will work.

Comment: You can edit the original post and include the full output. Also try to add `set -x` as the first line after shebang to print more info on what is being executed and run it

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I did not have permission to execute bash script on that directory. When I got the permission, the script worked.